# Is there a way to set the color of plotly legend items?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, legend, scatter-plot

I want to visualize multiple boolean arrays using Scatter traces with timestamps as x and the array-index as y. The values should be visualized using the colors. However, what I do not like is that the colors of the legend items are always set to the first element of these traces. Is there a way to set the legend item color independently? Here's a minimal example to show the issue.

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

data = np.random.randint(0,2,(3, 50))

traces = [
    go.Scatter(
        x = np.arange(len(line)),
        y = np.ones(len(line)) * i,
        mode='markers',
        marker={
            'color': line,
            'cmin': 0,
            'cmax': 1,
            'colorscale': [[0, 'red'], [1, 'green']]
        },
    ) for i, line in enumerate(data)
]

fig = go.Figure(traces)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set the legend item colors independently for each trace in Plotly, you can use a custom legend by adding

```
showlegend=False
```

to each trace and then manually creating the legend using separate scatter traces.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate scatter traces"? More traces without data points? That would not really be a correct legend, because I would not be able to hide some traces by clicking on them, right?